# Pass Data even if it gets blocked From SQL

Tags: sql

I have some data to escape sql check. Heres my code to check sql if its valid or not valid.

```
SELECT * 
FROM tb_event 
WHERE (time_start BETWEEN '$dateTimeStart' AND '$dateTimeFinish'
   OR time_finish BETWEEN '$dateTimeStart' AND '$dateTimeFinish')
```

The code above will check all values if valid then it will be released.
But i have some field for name = position.. If the position is `head of office`. The system will check that the results are valid even though there are the same dates.

Example :

I will input date from `2022-02-06` to `2022-02-08`

Table event to check :

```
ID | name | date_start | date_finish | position
1  | Ani  | 2022-02-06 | 2022-02-08  | head of office
2  | BAY  | 2022-02-06 | 2022-02-08  | staff
3  | CIE  | 2022-02-06 | 2022-02-08  | staff
4  | DON  | 2022-02-04 | 2022-02-05  | staff
5  | EVY  | 2022-02-04 | 2022-02-05  | staff
```

The table I expect to appear

```
ID | name | date_start | date_finish | position
1  | Ani  | 2022-02-06 | 2022-02-08  | head of office
4  | DON  | 2022-02-04 | 2022-02-05  | staff
5  | EVY  | 2022-02-04 | 2022-02-05  | staff
```

Because other is staff and the date already exists .

Comment: Please provide a few rows of sample data and the expected result.

Comment: I have updated !

Comment: Shouldn't just be a matter of appending `OR position = 'head of office'`?

Comment: ive tried that.. not working.
`WHERE (time_start BETWEEN '$dateTimeStart' AND '$dateTimeFinish'
   OR time_finish BETWEEN '$dateTimeStart' AND '$dateTimeFinish'
OR position = 'head of office' )`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't mention the database so I'll assume you are using PostgreSQL. You can do:

```
SELECT * 
FROM t 
WHERE (date_start BETWEEN '2022-02-06' AND '2022-02-08'
   OR date_finish BETWEEN '2022-02-06' AND '2022-02-08')
   OR position = 'head of office'
```

Result:

```
 id  name  date_start                date_finish               position       
 --- ----- ------------------------- ------------------------- -------------- 
 1   Ani   2022-02-06T00:00:00.000Z  2022-02-08T00:00:00.000Z  head of office 
 2   BAY   2022-02-06T00:00:00.000Z  2022-02-08T00:00:00.000Z  staff          
 3   CIE   2022-02-06T00:00:00.000Z  2022-02-08T00:00:00.000Z  staff
```

See running example at [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/r9EYf9DUe4mSm4sMCtVBdn/0).

Comment: Thanks man,, it worked.. I've merged with my other tables and it worked.